# How to package an air lib to another Android Library

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have added an aar file to my libs folder in Another Android Library Module.

And I have solved the dependenice on Android Library to aar in this way:

```
repositories {
    flatDir() {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/someAAR.aar')
}
```

Now the question is I found when I package this android Library, someAAR.aar would not been found in the output packages libs folder, so how can I tell the gradle to package aar file to another aar's libs folder?

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your `dependencies`
:-

> `compile(name: 'someAAR', ext: 'aar')`

This will definately work :)